# LESS CSS - interpolation on mapped variables

Tags: less

I'm trying to automate a nested map scenario using LESS CSS.

Consider the following single level map:

```
    .map(@keys) {
        each(@keys, {
            @{value} : @index;
        });
    }
```

Called something like this:

```
.render-maps() {
    @arr: child1, child2, child3;

    @text-colors: {
        @map(@arr);
    }
}
```

This works fine for single level maps where the output is a simple key and value, however I want to create a second level map - like below - but I can't get it to compile:

```
.nested-map(@arr1, @arr2) {
    each(@arr1, {
        // I cannot get the compiler to output with a prefix '@' on parent!!!
        @parent@{index} : { 
            each(@arr2, {
                @{value} : @index;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Can it be done? If so, any advice appreciated.

UPDATE

Here's what I'm trying to achieve, just in case there's a better solution:

I have a number of base colors, these are held as variables in themes.

```
@primary: #000000;
```

For each base color, there may be a contrasting "on" color - representing text etc.

```
@on-primary: #ffffff;
```

For each "on" color, there maybe a number of categories - text, icons, borders.

... and for each category, there could be multiple states and each state uses a different opacity.

For instance,

icons have 3 states - active, inactive, disabled - each with a different opacity but using the same "on" color.

You could choose to place icons on the background or on a colored surface, so there are multiple themes as well.

To summarise, there could be hundreds of different permutations - which I don't want to maintain individually as variables.

Instead, I create a number of key variables/lists and mixins  so that I can generate all of the variations.

```
@primary: #000000; // 10 of these
@on-primary: #ffffff;
@icon-variants: active, inactive, disabled;
@icon-opacity-on-primary: 70, 50, 38;
```

Once, I have all my variants, I retrieve colors via a mixin. Here's an example of a single level map for colors.

```
.get-color(@color) {
    @colors: {
        .map-colors();
    }
    @return: color(@colors[$@color]);
}
```

This type of approach means that I can only need to know a theme "primary", from which I can get the correct, "on" colors and any variants for text, icons, borders, and any state of any variant suing just a handful of mixins.

For example: `.get-text-color(high-emphasis, on-primary)[];`

Here's how I have to map 2 level maps because I can't do it automatically:

```
.get-text-color(@theme; @type: high) {
    @text-colors: {
        @on-primary: { .map-text-color(on-primary); }
        @on-primary-dark: { .map-text-color(on-primary-dark); }
        @on-primary-light: { .map-text-color(on-primary-light); }
        @on-secondary: { .map-text-color(on-secondary); }
        @on-error: { .map-text-color(on-error); }
        @on-surface: { .map-text-color(on-surface); }
        @on-background: { .map-text-color(on-background); }
        @on-light: { .map-text-color(on-light); }
        @on-dark: { .map-text-color(on-dark); }
    }
    @return: color(@text-colors[@@theme][$@type]);
}
```

Which results in 30 colors - 10 x 3 states.

Comment: You can't declare variables like this (and yes, it was me who prohibited a code like this directly) - what is you goal? (This definitely an XY-problem). I.e. please post you pseudo code map and how you're going to use it - it's 99.9999% there's much more compact and clear solution.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for your reply. I've tried to explain what I'm trying to achieve (ABOVE), but ultimately, I don't want to maintain 100's of color variables. The way, that it currently works means  I don't have to depend on  a single theme via a mixin, as in .loadTheme(green) { // a number of green variants }, instead I can retrieve any color variant what I want from anywhere .

Comment: Your maname mistake is basically the same as in some of your prev. Qs here. You keep trying to encode an entity parameter in its name. Like for examlpe instead of writing a `srqt` function to be used as `sqrt(2), sqrt(3), sqrt(4)` you'd try to *generate* a set of function named `sqrt_2, sqrt_3, sqrt_4`. etc. In your case above what you need is a mixin (or a map) that creates a value from two parameters directly w/o involving any intermediate set of values. Though I still can't suggest a ready-to-use solution w/o knowing (I understand the 10x3 thing) how exactly the end values are generated....

Comment: So for example, when you call the mixin as `.get-text-color(high-emphasis, on-primary)` - what should be the returned value in terms of you initial data set (the one with `@primary ... @icon-opacity-on-primary`)?

Comment: E.g., if I understand it right, if you call something like `.get-icon-color(inactive, primary)` it should return a value like `fade(@primary, extract(@icon-opacity-on-primary, <index>))` or so. I.e. the only trick there is to get the value of `<index>` (which is pretty easy) and requires no *new* structures/maps to be generated at all... Just the code to generate *the returned value*.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Your last assumption is correct, but how do I get the index?

Comment: *how do I get the index* - something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/a12a361d0076a637e8051b577015bf66).